# If $S$ is the simplex defined by the convex hull of $0$ and vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_p$, how show $Volume(S) = \pm \frac{1}{n!} det(a_1, \ldots, a_p)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

If $S$ is the simplex defined by the convex hull of $0$ and vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_p$, I would like to show $Volume(S) = \pm \frac{1}{n!}det(a_1, \ldots, a_p)$. In other words, the volume of the simplex is plus or minus the determinant of a matrix $A$ which has $(a_1, \ldots, a_p)$ as its columns.

My technique is to recognize that $S = \{v:v=\sum_{i=1}^pc_ia_i, \ c_i \geq 0, \ \text{and} \sum_{i=1}^p \leq 1\}$.

But, from here I am not sure what to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you mean $\frac{1}{n!}$ times the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Yes, that is correct, thanks, I corrected it!

Comment: If the vectors are linearly dependent, the answer follows immediately. If the vectors are linearly independent, then by the change of variable formula in multivariate calculus, it suffices to prove that the volume of the standard simplex is $\frac1{n!}$, but this follows from Fubini's theorem and mathematical induction.

Comment: @user1551 The change of variables formula is a pretty big hammer.

Comment: @MattSamuel Why? You need to define the volume of a simplex, and the most familiar way is to use a multiple integral. In this context the use of change of variable formula is quite natural, I believe.

Comment: @user1551 I'd certainly like to see this fleshed out into an answer, if you're so inclined.